# How do I get significance measure of my elastic net coefficient

Tags: r

I'm new to elastic net. I'm implementing elastic net in R using following code

```
model <- train(
LnSales ~., data = train_data, method = "glmnet",
trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
tuneLength = 100
)
```

Can you suggest me the steps to get significance value of the variables used in my model? Sorry, I can't able to share the data

Comment: Not sure what exact values of the significance are you looking for, other than those that are already implemented in ``caret`` package that you're using, but you may be also interested in [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410173/lasso-regression-p-values-and-coefficients/410196#410196)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Nutle. By significance, I'm looking for p value of coefficients. The link you shared contains p value using `cv.glmnet` . How can I get same using train function?

Comment: You will get the same results - note that in your code you are using ``method = "glmnet"`` with ``"cv"`` in ``trainControl``, which essentially calls the same ``cv.glmnet``.